# VB OpenFileDialog Not Displaying Correctly

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, windows-ce

I am having trouble with the OpenFileDialog class in Visual Studio 2008. I am programming in VB.net for an embedded application using .Net Compact Framework 3.5 on a WEC 7 unit.

I would like a button in a sub-form to allow the user to select a file using the OpenFileDialog. However, every time the user clicks the button opening this dialog, the dialog does not appear and the form appears to instantly close. The parent form becomes unresponsive (as if the dialog was open, but not accessible) and when I pause the code in debug mode the system appears to be waiting for input on the file select (which, again, is not visible).

My first thoughts were that this was an issue with which form was on top, or with my code (see below), but I have copy-pasted the code into other buttons of other subforms and had no issue. I have tried removing the showdialog from the if statement with no change in results. I have even put the code within the load function of the form - where it worked just fine. I am pretty well at a loss to explain what is wrong.

Can any of you spot the problem?

Here is my code from the button.Click function:

```
    Dim FileSelect As New OpenFileDialog

    FileSelect.Filter = "Files|*.*"

    If FileSelect.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        Dim test As String = FileSelect.FileName
    End If
```

Comment: can you try make sure all your exception settings are turned on and try again? An exception might be getting thrown but your debugger isn't raising it. EDIT: I ask because I tried your code copy pasted and it works fine for me, so there must be something else in your code causing this behavior.

Comment: I added all the exceptions, but no exceptions are being thrown. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Is the parent form also shown as ShowDialog too?

Comment: Yes - the main form shows a sub-form via showdialog. This sub-form opens the parent of this button via showdialog.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are running this code in background thread . it maybe get a ThreadStateException

Comment: I don't believe so - I specifically enabled the ThreadStateException and tried again, but no exception was thrown. Is there something else I need to check to verify this?

Comment: sometimes exceptions doesn't appear immediately while debugging ... try put your code between TRY and CATCH ... `msgbox (ex.message)` ... maybe it can show you something

Comment: That is a good idea. Unfortunately, when I put the code in a try-catch it still behaves as if everything is still working, but it is still not showing. The catch is never triggered.